# Does a schur-concave function needs to be symmetric?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Does a schur-concave function need to be symmetric? If not, how can we check schur-concavity for a non-symmetric function?

I know this lemma (schur condition, [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=MqE-6XYPOdsC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=jorswieck%20boche&source=bl&ots=5KjrPPMudg&sig=KuLOp5YJcZbX8FvYeaVROKuFma4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dp3fUrXcK6PJygOV1YGwAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=jorswieck%20boche&f=false))

Let $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and let $f: \mathcal{I}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Necessary and sufficient conditions for $f$ to be schur-concave on $\mathcal{I}^n$ are, $f$ is symmetric on $\mathcal{I}^n$ and,

$$(x_1 - x_2)\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_1}} - \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}}\right) \le 0$$

Comment: I think your question needs additional tags.:-)

Comment: @B.S. yeah, thanx :)

Comment: Defined on a symmetric set, the function is symmetric if it is Schur concave / convex.

Comment: @Macavity  well, what if $\mathcal{I}^n$  is not symmetric? By the way, is this what you mean by a symmetric set? $\mathcal{S}$ is symmetric if $\forall x \in \mathcal{S}$ all permutations of $x$ also lie in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Yes, that would be a symmetric set. If the set isn't symmetric, I would check if some superset of it is symmetric, see if the function can be defined on it, and apply the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If $x \in \mathcal{I}^n$ and $x \pi \in \mathcal{I}^n$ for any permutation $\pi$, we have $x \succ x \pi \succ x$, so if $f$ is Schur concave (or convex), we must have $f(x) \le  f(x\pi) \le  f(x) \implies f(x) = f(x\pi)$ for any such permutation.

Comment: Can you please explain $x \succeq x\pi \succeq x$ relation?I think I saw it once more in Olkin book, but didn't get it.So it says if the domain (or its possible superset) of a function is symmetric, and the function is not symmetric it is not schure-convex or concave. For example, $\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\alpha_i x_i}$ defined on a polytope is not schur-concave.

Comment: We say $x \succ y$ or $x$ majorizes $y$ when, $x_i, y_i$ are the respective components in descending order, $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^m y_i$ for **all** $1 \le m < n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$.  By the definition, it is easy to see that the actual order of the components of each vector is immaterial, hence $x \succ x\pi \succ x$.  Hope that is clear.